# Chainging methods

Tags: java, android

> Add a second Toast notification that combines these two lines into one line (make sure you leave the first two lines intact!). For this second Toast, chain the `show()` method to the `makeText()` method, and use whatever String message you want.

What's wrong with this?

```
Toast allDoneToast = Toast.makeText(this, "All done!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
allDoneToast.show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the point of the task is to combine those two lines into a single line of code by chaining methods together - neither solution is "wrong" or "right", I suspect they just want you to know you can do so.

You chain methods by calling one immediately on the result of the other, like this:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "All done!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Nothing.**

But there's no need to keep a reference to a `allDoneToast` Toast object if you aren't going to use it afterwards.  In this case, using a anonymous object makes a bit more sense, unless you have a good reason not to do so.